# Android Studio - Multiple Bluetooth Connection

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

I'm making a project where I need to connect via my Android Studio App two devices and continously send and recieve information.

How can I make this in terms of code in the Android Studio Java language?

Thanks

Comment: No offense but this is a very vague question. Do some research and ask a more specific/streamlined question.

Comment: https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-direct

Answer (score 0):

You can find this [library](https://github.com/arissa34/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library) useful. Here is [a tutorial](http://arissa34.github.io/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library/) on how to use it.